# Add the value name to the previous column from the first table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this Two Tables

TB1:

```
Code    Name
----    ----
25      Nour
14      saly
```

TB2:

```
OldCode   NewCode    NewName
 -------   -------    -------
  25          14        Saly
```

My requirement is to add a mew column `OldName`. The resulting table should look like this:

```
OldCode    OldName      NewCode    NewName
 -------   -------      -------    -------
 25          Nour         14        Saly
```

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried and why didn't it work? You've told us what you want to do, but not showm us the difficulty you're having achieving this.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, what happened?

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want a join?

```
select tb2.oldcode, told.name, tb2.newcode, tb2.newname
from tb2 join
     tb1 told
     on tb2.oldcode = told.code;
```

I am curious why the new name in `tb2` doesn't match the name for the code in `tb1`.  I would expect them to be the same.